# Converting .mp4 to .webm with FFMPEG

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg

Any chance someone can help me make this a 2 or 3 pass command:

*Using "FFmpeg Win64 Static build by Kyle Schwarz, compiled on: Sep 19 2012 16:31:43" in the Command Prompt of Windows7(x64). I am a newbie to FFMPEG and trying to convert videos for my website from **.mp4** to **.webm** (videos edited and mixed in AdobePremiereProCS6 where then encoded into **.mp4** from **.mts** Canon HXG10 recordings). Original video file is **1080p** quality.*

> c:\ff/ffmpeg -i c:\ff/xxx.mp4 -codec:v libvpx -quality good -cpu-used
>   0 -b:v 7000k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1500k -threads 8
>   -vf scale=-1:1080 -codec:a libvorbis -b:a 192k -f webm c:\ff/xxx.webm

Answer (score 2):

as '1 pass' the follosing  works for me on build including vorbis, libvpx...

for hints on 2 pass libvpx see [here](http://snipplr.com/view/55804/merge-one-slide--audio-using-ffmpeg--output-is-audio-only--in-video-container--one-slide-in-vid-track/)

```
rob@ Pictures$ ffmpeg -y -i me939371029.mp4 -r 30  out3.webm

ffmpeg version git-2012-08-29-85c8303 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 29 2012 08:59:14 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      51. 70.100 / 51. 70.100
  libavcodec     54. 54.100 / 54. 54.100
  libavformat    54. 25.104 / 54. 25.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 14.100 /  3. 14.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'me939371029.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.22.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 343 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p, 1296x972 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 316 kb/s, 0.57 fps, 0.50 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[libvpx @ 0x1e7f500] v1.1.0
Output #0, webm, to 'out3.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.25.104
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 1296x972 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, mono, flt
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libvpx)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvorbis)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvorbis @ 0x1e67060] Que input is backward in time
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=     122kB time=00:00:07.99 bitrate= 124.6kbits/s    
video:51kB audio:63kB subtitle:0 global headers:3kB muxing overhead 3.241658%
```

Comment: Thank for the cryptic response. It is appreciated though.

Comment: Still not understanding or getting help out of your answer. More info needed.

Comment: i gave u one example of MP4 --> web.m  in 1 pass mode
then as 2 pass example for a different mode provided a diff link. you wanted 2 pass mp4 --> webm.. you should just be able to take the 1 pass example and break it up into 2 passes...

Comment: I'm trying. I keep getting stuck with this. I'm still here working it out. Thx again for your input. I will post more info tomorrow. Many sites recommend using the VP8 encoder for the video. Maybe this is part of my problem too.