# Convert mp4 to webm with transparency?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transparency, mp4, webm

I know how to [convert mp4 to webm with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544754/converting-mp4-to-webm-with-ffmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -y -i me939371029.mp4 -r 30  out3.webm
```

But I'd like to use [webm transparency](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video). That guide uses Blender, but Blender's a desktop tool that's not easily automated and only outputs PNGs that must be converted to video. **I'd like a command line app that accepts video in, a color, and a video out.** E.g.:

```
some-app -i video.mp4 -transparent ff0000 -o video.webm
```

I'd be surprised if something like this wasn't already in ffmpeg, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: H.264 doesn't have alpha so what's the result that you want?

Comment: @Mulvya Yes, that's correct. I want the H264 video which has a green background, turned into a webm, with the specified color made transparent in the webm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the color to be keyed out is `00ff00`, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -vf "colorkey=0x00ff00:0.1:0.1,format=yuva420p" out.webm
```

In `colorkey=0x00ff00:0.1:0.1`

Parts are seperated by `:`. The first part is the key color. The color

> 0x00ff00

is green.

the 2nd is similarity

> 0.01 matches only the exact key color, while 1.0 matches everything.

and the 3rd is blend percentage

> 0.0 makes pixels either fully transparent, or not transparent at all.
>
> Higher values result in semi-transparent pixels, with a higher transparency the more similar the pixels color is to the key color.

See the [ffmpeg colorkey documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey)

---

**Resolving *auto_alt_ref* error**

When you run into an error saying:
`Transparency encoding with auto_alt_ref does not work Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`

You can disable *auto_alt_ref* by adding the parameter `-auto-alt-ref 0`

Comment: Sweet and thanks! I needed to to `brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvpx` first. Is `format=yuva420p' needed?

Comment: The filter works in RGB space. So, to preserve alpha, the format should be prescribed somewhere, whether inside the chain as currently or outside as `-pix_fmt yuva420p`

Comment: Thanks! Understood re: `yuv` + alpha (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV), but does the `420p' limit me to 420p output?

Comment: There is also the [chromakey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#chromakey) filter that works in YUV.

Comment: *does the `420p' limit me to 420p output?* - no, that's pixel chroma sampling i.e. color resolution, not image dimensions.