# Convert mov with Alpha to VP9 Webm with Alpha Using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

I am trying to convert a **mov** with alpha transparency to **webm** with alpha transparency, as seen [here](http://simpl.info/videoalpha/). I followed the steps explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video?hl=en) to no avail.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678964/convert-mp4-to-webm-with-transparency#answer-34682312) I was able to remove all the black in the video, thus making it transparent but this is not what I need as I already have a transparent **mov** and would like to convert that to transparent **webm** format.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -vf "colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0.1,format=yuva420p" out.webm
```

This is the `ffprobe` output of the video I would like to convert to webm with transparency.

```
built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.2_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2016-01-17 16:04:07
    encoder         : Mac OS X v? (AVF 1046.9.1, CM 1731.15.20, x86_64)
    encoder-eng     : Mac OS X v? (AVF 1046.9.1, CM 1731.15.20, x86_64)
  Duration: 00:00:06.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 63966 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (ap4h / 0x68347061), yuva444p10le(bt470bg/smpte240m/bt709), 1920x1080, 63963 kb/s, 25.03 fps, 25 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-17 16:04:07
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 4444
```

I've also tried the following command which didn't work for me either.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2000k -pass 1 -an -f webm output.webm
```

I'm using version 2.8.4 of ffmpeg on a Mac, installed with brew. 2.8.5 is the latest version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p out.webm
```

Comment: How can I set a bit rate to this?

Comment: Add `-b:v 2000k` for 2mbps avg rate.

Comment: That's VP8, not VP9.

Comment: Yes, at time of answer, VP9 didn't support alpha. Change to `libvpx-vp9`

Comment: Transparency encoding with auto_alt_ref does not work i got this error

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan try adding `-auto-alt-ref 0` right before the output

Comment: @TheForgot3n1 If you want to debug, open a new Q with full command & log.

Answer (score 18):

Since [2016-07-13](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/acca56d9629b7fc158ce188190d22314c3d92c39), it's possible to encode *VP9/webm* videos with alpha channel (*VP9a*). However, the command you use here will create a *VP8a* video. Assuming you got a copy of **ffmpeg** compiled after that date, all you need is change the `libvpx` to `libvpx-vp9`. You don't need the `yuva420p` conversion either (is selected by default).

Comment: `yuva420p` does not seem to be selected by default in my case. Upd.: though it appears to be a [ffprobe bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8344) since in browser transparency does work

Answer (score 6):

All of the other solutions resulted in a video of subpar quality. Please ensure that you define the bitrate to your liking. I changed mine from 1M to 2M and was satisfied.

`ffmpeg -i "Model 1 V1.mov" -f webm -c:v libvpx -b:v 2M -acodec libvorbis -auto-alt-ref 0 model1v3.webm -hide_banner`

If you're using After Effects or Premiere Pro, there's also this [plugin](http://www.fnordware.com/WebM/), which can be used in Adobe Media Encoder.

Answer (score 2):

This is the command that worked for me for VP8.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p -b:v 2M -auto-alt-ref 0 output.webm
```

Accepted option did not work.

Answer (score 0):

[WebM-alpha](http://wiki.webmproject.org/alpha-channel) is only defined for VP8. It doesn't work at all for VP9 right now.

Comment: That's not true. VP9 supports alpha with the right pixel format.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the accepted answers along with the suggestions from the comments.
This works for me.

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p -auto-alt-ref 0 -b:v 2000k output.webm`