# Error "Transparency encoding with auto_alt_ref does not work" when converting a .mov with Alpha to .webm with alpha with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, alpha, webm, mov

I am trying to convert a .mov file with alpha transparency into a .webm file and have been following this thread for help: [Convert mov with Alpha to VP9 Webm with Alpha Using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856236/convert-mov-with-alpha-to-vp9-webm-with-alpha-using-ffmpeg)

The command line I have been using is

```
ffmpeg -r 24/1 -i Desktop/Skel_Walk_1.mov -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p Desktop/Skel_Walk_1.webm
```

However when I go to run the command it comes up with 2 errors

```
Transparency encoding with auto_alt_ref does not work
```

and

```
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 
- maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I am not too sure what the problem is here, any suggestions, I am very confused!

Answer (score 62):

I think I may have solved this, adding `-auto-alt-ref 0` before the output fixed this issue!!

Working Command

```
ffmpeg -i Desktop/Skel_Walk_1.mov -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p -auto-alt-ref 0 Desktop/Skel_Walk_1.webm
```

Comment: This unfortunately also removes alpha, do you know of any workaround that doesn't remove alpha?

Comment: @AugustBjornberg use `libvpx-vp9` instead of `libvpx` in the command. This will preserve the alpha

Answer (score 0):

@ThomTTP's solution is correct, but the Alpha channel is gone.

```
-vf "premultiply=inplace=1"
```

If you use the options together, you may not lose the alpha channel in VP8.