# Cannot get transparent background with ffmpeg (HEVC to VP8/VP9)

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, hevc

I want to convert a mp4 video to any other format that supports video-transparency. I've done it in the past but I cannot get it to work again.

I've followed the same guides as before:

- [Convert mp4 to webm with transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678964/convert-mp4-to-webm-with-transparency)
- [Convert mov with Alpha to VP9 Webm with Alpha Using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856236/convert-mov-with-alpha-to-vp9-webm-with-alpha-using-ffmpeg)
- [Error "Transparency encoding with auto_alt_ref does not work" when converting a .mov with Alpha to .webm with alpha with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588064/error-transparency-encoding-with-auto-alt-ref-does-not-work-when-converting-a#45588400)

The input video is a HEVC (h265), and the background I want to remove is full white. I'm using the following command to make the conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -b:v 4M -vf "colorkey=0xffffff:0.1:0.0,format=yuva420p" -auto-alt-ref 0 transparent.webm
```

I've also tried with VP9 (libvpx-vp9) with same result. The conversion of a single frame from a PNG source  (screen captured frame) works ok.

Any idea about where I could be failing in?

I hope there's nothing missing, thanks in advance.

PS I'm getting a warning at the transcode process, I don't think is anything important but here it's in case is something relevant: `[swscaler @ 000001e3b0dc7a40] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.`

Answer (score 5):

Ok, the error was on the video player (VLC) seems that VLC does not support video transparency. On the browser it's correctly displayed with the transparent background.